# Could a web browser in OSX use a browser app served from a VM running on the same machine?

Tags: linux, macos, virtual-machine

You may ask why I would need to do this. I am planning a web app and the server software i want to use can run either on Linux or Windows, but not on OSX. Whilst most users will be part of a network so a linux/Win server is not a problem, a few Mac users may be self employed and want to run in standalone mode on their one Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mac users will need to be able to access the virtual machine over http or https.

This should be fairly straightforward by using the IP of the Virtual Machine, or if the web app requires a particular hostname then you may need to edit /etc/hosts on the mac to resolve that to the VM IP.

It should make no difference which VM software you are running.  I believe the three most common ones are:

Parallels Desktop for Mac (costs around $50)
VMWare Fusion (costs around $50)
VirtualBox (free)

You should find it fairly straightforward to supply VM images for all three of those if your users need it, assuming you have copies of the software you can use to create them.

I've used Parallels and VMWare Fusion quite a lot, and found them both to be incredibly simple to set up.  I've had a few more networking problems with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A web app as long as its compatible with the mac browser used, should work fine, being in a VM shouldnt change a thing